# SPRESENSEのカメラ仕様とフォーカス制御について

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEのカメラモジュールの仕様として、以下の公式サイトには、
有効焦点距離＝2.74mmと焦点距離＝1.5m、焦点範囲＝77.5～237.06cm
と記載されています．

カメラにあまり詳しくないのですが、カメラと撮影する対象物との距離は焦点範囲内に収めて、
さらに、1.5mになるように合わせるのが一番良いという理解で正しいでしょうか？

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89

また、旧ドキュメントには、カメラ制御として、AF制御やマニュアルといった記載がありましたが、
新ドキュメントにはそれらの記載がありません。もうこのようなフォーカス制御はできなくなった
ということでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

このカメラモジュールにはアクチュエータが載っていないので、そもそもオートフォーカスができないカメラです。旧ドキュメントは明らかな誤記ですね。

固定焦点で焦点範囲（被写界深度？）＝77.5～237.06cmということですので、1.5m はあくまで推奨で 77.5cm~2mの間は焦点があっているということだと思います。

ただ、口径を絞ったレンズに加え、SPRESENSEは使えるメモリが少ないので遠くのものを十分な解像度で写せる能力もありません。77.5cm 以遠のものは焦点があっていると考えてもよいと思います。